# Internal Server Error 500 on .PHP pages only

Tags: php, internal-server-error

This is a problem that has been occurring a few times a week for the last 12 months but it never used to last for longer than an hour maximum, sometimes a lot less. This time however, it has been showing for nearly 18 hours so clearly it's not going to go away on it's own this time. I've done the usual google search and also checked similar questions on here but nothing gave me a solution.

I have hosting with HostPapa and the error log within cPanel doesn't help me either. It normally just says that a file called robots.txt cannot be found and it also can't find a 404.shtml file. At this moment in time, the error log is completely empty, even if I try to visit the site beforehand.

Best theories I heard was either Wrong Permissions and/or disabling Zend Guard?

[Fri Sep 26 15:54:05 2014] [error] [client 62.24.222.132] File does not exist: /home/tmsth125/public_html/robots.txt, referer: http://tmsthermalstore.com/robots.txt
[Fri Sep 26 15:53:56 2014] [error] [client 62.24.222.131] File does not exist: /home/tmsth125/public_html/404.shtml, referer: http://tmsthermalstore.com/helloworld.php
[Fri Sep 26 15:53:56 2014] [error] [client 62.24.222.131] File does not exist: /home/tmsth125/public_html/helloworld.php, referer: http://tmsthermalstore.com/helloworld.php

Comment: There MUST be a message in the error log unless you explicitly disabled them in your config.

Comment: Have you tried a basic PHP page, i.e. print "Hello world"; ?  to see if it's a generic problem or a problem with e.g. an include file that's in all of your php?

Comment: You have hosting that inexplicably craps out on you for up to an hour at a time, a few times per week, for the last year, and you are still using the company? What do their customer service have to say about this?

Comment: @JeffUK Yeah I've done a basic hello word and a phpinfo() test, both generated the error.

Comment: @Steve I haven't contacted them yet because I'm assuming the problem is my end.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Tried viewing the error log again and it gave me the usual ones, I've included them in the original question.

Comment: @CraigyCraigo If the errors (in the past) just go away again without you doing anything, then they are not related to your activity.

Comment: @CraigyCraigo You should contact your hoster. If a simple `<?php phpinfo();` fails, then the error is on their site. Other options: you have to enable PHP once in the config panel maybe?

Comment: @Steve I agree Steve, sounds logical.

Comment: @DanFromGermany I will contact them now, hopefully it is a problem on their side!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting Customer Support via Live Chat, they fixed the issue and confirmed it was related to permissions in the php.ini file.